# Extra white space on uitableview controller added on uitableview controller

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I've added uitable view on uiviewcontroller on storyboard but a white space comes on tableview as in the added image.After adjusting it in autolayout the white space goes but last two rows of tableview becomes unresponsive on simulator iphone 4.0 and iphone simulator 4.0 64 bits,I'm struck in this part from so many days Thanks in advance.

Please let me know What should be set cell in storyboard,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { 
// Return the number of sections. 
return [codesArray count]; 
}
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
// Return the number of rows in the section. 
return 1; 
} 


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
} 
UILabel *codeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101]; 
NSString *codeNameText=[codeNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
codeNameLabel.text = codeNameText;
return cell; 
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: are set cell in storyboard?

Comment: Can you share your tableView datasource and delegate methods.

Comment: Please let me know What should be set cell in storyboard,- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [codesArray count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return 1;

}

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
    
        UILabel *codeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    NSString *codeNameText=[codeNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];codeNameLabel.text = codeNameText;return cell;
}

Comment: where you are set orangeColor. and color set on which view?

Comment: thats on storyboard.I'm setting tableview cell background as orange colour.But the white space is not of tableview.it is added on tableview.